# button1_KeyPress = button1_Click? С# Form

Tags: c#

Привет! button1_KeyPress это тоже самое что button1_Click? Почему Visual Studio не находит ссылки для button1_KeyPress. Занимаюсь по старому учебнику и там в button1_KeyPres код по обработке нажимаемых клавиш с клавиатуры, какие можно нажимать, а какие нет.

Comment: что значит не  "не находит ссылки для button1_KeyPress"?

Comment: Ссылка в редакторе. Вот ссылка есть: http://i.imgur.com/fUpZwat.png

Comment: А вот ее нет: http://i.imgur.com/hRrvGO6.png

Comment: На этом рисунке, изображен кусок функции, что он должен находить?

Comment: Он обрабатывает нажимаемые символы с клавиатуры, но к сожалению он не работает. http://i.imgur.com/1sEAmae.png

Comment: Так, давайте сначала, где и что у вас не находит студия и зачем вы приводите код самописного аналога `Parse()`?

Comment: Ну мой код просто не работает. А редактор не находит ссылки к форме, как в случае с http://i.imgur.com/fUpZwat.png Я понял что лучше заменить всю конструкцию на Parse()?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

По моему вы просто, вы просто, что то не туда суете. Кнопка не принимает ввод текстовой информации и не хранит набранный вами текст, она может среагировать на нажатие какой то клавиши (например `Enter`). Если вам надо парсить числа введенные в текст-бокс то вам надо сделать, например, так:

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    try
    {
        N = Int32.Parse(textBox1.Text);
    }
    catch (FormatException error)
    {
        N = 0;
    }
}
```

Но возможен и вариант, что у вас в десигнере формы зависла строка, типа:

```
this.button1.KeyPress += new System.Windows.Forms.KeyPressEventHandler(this.button1_KeyPress);
```

после того как вы удалили из формы обработчик `KeyPress`, и теперь при компиляции вылетает сообщение, типа:

> 'WindowsFormsApplication2.Form1' does not contain a definition for
>   'button1_KeyPress' and no extension method 'button1_KeyPress'
>   accepting a first argument of type 'WindowsFormsApplication2.Form1'
>   ...

Может еще что то случилось, ваш вопрос уж очень не понятен.

**UPD**

Что бы кнопка срабатывала на `Enter` надо не писать обработчик, а в свойствах формы указать:

```
AcceptButton = {Имя вашей кнопки};
```

Ну или в конструкторе

Comment: Что мне нужно сделать что бы моя кнопка срабатывала на Enter? `this.button1.KeyPress += new System.Windows.Forms.KeyPressEventHandler(this.button1_KeyPress);` отсутствует.

Answer (score 1):

`Click` - это событие по нажатию кнопки мыши.
`KeyPress` - по нажатию клавиши на клавиатуре.
Разница очевидна.

Comment: А как мне создать button1_KeyPress? Созданный вручную button1_KeyPress не привязывается к форме.

Comment: вот неплохая статья о событиях в C#: https://habrahabr.ru/post/213809/. думаю, после прочтения многие вопросы отпадут.